# Find the PID of a process that uses a port on Windows

Tags: port

My service crash on startup with the classic:

```
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 9999
```

How can I find the process for killing it?

Comment: More complex alternative solutions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Just open a command shell and type (saying your port is 123456):

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "123456"
```

You will see everything you need.

The headers are:

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
 TCP    0.0.0.0:37             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1111
```

Comment: here how do i get only the pid, since it returns entire details

Comment: how to get the only PID form above results

Comment: or, `nestat -aon | findstr 123456`

Comment: Easy way to achieve this on windows is showed in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: for windows/cygwin, it probably would be 
netstat -a -n -o | grep "123456"

Comment: for more precise results, put a colon in front of the port number: find ":123456"

Answer (score 112):

**Find the PID of a process that uses a port on Windows** *(e.g. port: "9999")*

```
netstat -aon | find "9999"
```

`-a` Displays all connections and listening ports.

`-o` Displays the owning process ID associated with each connection.

`-n` Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.

*Output:*

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:9999       0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING       15776
```

**Then kill the process by PID**

```
taskkill /F /PID 15776
```

`/F` - Specifies to forcefully terminate the process(es).

*Note: You may need an extra permission (run from administrator) to kill some certain processes*

Comment: Why doesn't netstat exit unless you give it the n flag?

Comment: @JaredBeach - it's waiting for inverse DNS name resolution, so it will eventually finish after the timeouts are done.  If this hangs on *internal* IPs, then it suggests an issue with your local DNS servers.

Answer (score 27):

**Command:**

```
netstat -aon | findstr 4723
```

**Output:**

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:4723           0.0.0.0:0                LISTENING       10396
```

Now cut the process ID, "10396", using the `for` command in Windows.

**Command:**

```
for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| findstr 4723') do @echo %~nxa
```

**Output:**

10396

If you want to cut the 4th number of the value means "LISTENING" then command in Windows.

**Command:**

```
for /f "tokens=4" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| findstr 4723') do @echo %~nxa
```

**Output:**

LISTENING

Comment: any suggestions for filtering unique PID as the command sometimes returns same process multiple times?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do this programmatically you can use some of the options given to you as follows in a PowerShell script:

```
$processPID =  $($(netstat -aon | findstr "9999")[0] -split '\s+')[-1]
taskkill /f /pid $processPID
```

However; be aware that the more accurate you can be the more precise your PID result will be. If you know which host the port is supposed to be on you can narrow it down a lot. `netstat -aon | findstr "0.0.0.0:9999"` will only return one application and most llikely the correct one. Only searching on the port number may cause you to return processes that only happens to have `9999` in it, like this:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:9999                        0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING       15776
UDP    [fe80::81ad:9999:d955:c4ca%2]:1900  *:*                             12331
```

The most likely candidate usually ends up first, but if the process has ended before you run your script you may end up with PID 12331 instead and killing the wrong process.

Answer (score 5):

After some fiddling with a script I came to this action. Copy and save it in a .bat file:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %%i IN (`netstat -aon ^| find "3306"`) DO taskkill /F /PID %%i
```

Change 'find "3306"' in the port number which needs to be free. Then run the file as administrator. It will kill all the processes running on this port.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell (Core-compatible) one-liner to ease copypaste scenarios:

```
netstat -aon | Select-String 8080 | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\s+', ',' } | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header @('Empty', 'Protocol', 'AddressLocal', 'AddressForeign', 'State', 'PID') | ForEach-Object { $portProcess = Get-Process | Where-Object Id -eq $_.PID; $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'ProcessName' -NotePropertyValue $portProcess.ProcessName; Write-Output $_ } | Sort-Object ProcessName, State, Protocol, AddressLocal, AddressForeign | Select-Object  ProcessName, State, Protocol, AddressLocal, AddressForeign | Format-Table
```

Output:

```
ProcessName State     Protocol AddressLocal AddressForeign
----------- -----     -------- ------------ --------------
System      LISTENING TCP      [::]:8080    [::]:0
System      LISTENING TCP      0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0
```

Same code, developer-friendly:

```
$Port = 8080

# Get PID's listening to $Port, as PSObject
$PidsAtPortString = netstat -aon `
  | Select-String $Port
$PidsAtPort = $PidsAtPortString `
  | ForEach-Object { `
      $_ -replace '\s+', ',' `
  } `
  | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header @('Empty', 'Protocol', 'AddressLocal', 'AddressForeign', 'State', 'PID')

# Enrich port's list with ProcessName data
$ProcessesAtPort = $PidsAtPort `
  | ForEach-Object { `
    $portProcess = Get-Process `
      | Where-Object Id -eq $_.PID; `
    $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'ProcessName' -NotePropertyValue $portProcess.ProcessName; `
    Write-Output $_;
  }

# Show output
$ProcessesAtPort `
  | Sort-Object    ProcessName, State, Protocol, AddressLocal, AddressForeign `
  | Select-Object  ProcessName, State, Protocol, AddressLocal, AddressForeign `
  | Format-Table
```

Comment: We already know that it is "java" using the port.  The goal is to find the PID so we can kill it.

Answer (score -1):

This helps to find PID using port number.

```
lsof -i tcp:port_number
```

Comment: After typing the command I got `'lsof' is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

Comment: Works in Linux.

Comment: This question is about Windows