# Can't run Windows Application Driver Address 'http://127.0.0.1:4723/' is already in use

Tags: windows, windows-application-driver

Implemented [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver)

Trying to start Windows Application Driver C#

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe";                
p.Start();
```

Error:

> Address 'http://127.0.0.1:4723/' is already in use
> Failed to initialize: 0x80004005

Error running it Windows Application Driver c# code:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4723/session timed out after 60 seconds.

**C# Code:**

```
var appPath = @"ApplicationPath";
var windowsApplicationDriverUrl = "http://localhost:4723";
var appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", appPath);

session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(windowsApplicationDriverUrl), appiumOptions);
```

Run

> [netstat -a -n -o | find "4723"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952663/find-the-pid-of-a-process-that-uses-a-port-on-windows)

I find the PID is for

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:4723           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

The System runs the PID

> tasklist

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0          8 K
System                           4 Services                   0      1,440 K
```

Windows Application driver doesn't run because something is already hogging the port.
Is this anti-virus? How do you fix?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately decided to just run the application on another port.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "28399";                
var p = Process.Start(startInfo);

Console.WriteLine("start");
var appPath = @"ApplicationPath";
var windowsApplicationDriverUrl = "http://localhost:28399";
var appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", appPath);

session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(windowsApplicationDriverUrl), appiumOptions);
```